# map osmdata cycleways in R - how to include cyclosm cycleways?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I'm currently trying to make a map of cycleways in Kiel, Germany in R. On the osm map online, one can use the layer cyclosm to view all cycleways, but when I map them with the osmdata package in R, the cycleways are incomplete (compared to here: [Kiel cyclosm layer](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/27021#map=12/54.3155/10.1957&layers=Y). Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

So far, I've been choosing cycleways as the value of the key "highways". I'm wondering whether there is another way to retrieve the cycleways from cyclosm?

```
# Libraries
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

kiel <-
  osmdata::getbb("Kiel") %>% 
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 25*100) %>%
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "admin_level", 
    value = "6"
  ) %>% 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() %$% 
  osm_multipolygons %>% 
  dplyr::filter(osm_id == "27021") %>% # filter on city level
  dplyr::select(geometry) %>%
  sf::st_transform() 

cycle <-
  osmdata::getbb("Kiel") %>% 
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 25*100) %>%
# is there any better way to choose cycleways?
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "highway", 
    value = c(
      "cycleway"
    )
  ) %>% 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() %$% 
  osm_lines %>% 
  dplyr::select(geometry) %>%
  sf::st_transform() %>% 
  sf::st_intersection(kiel) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    sf::st_is(., "LINESTRING")
  )

water <-
  osmdata::getbb("Kiel") %>% 
  osmdata::opq(timeout = 25*100) %>%
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "natural", 
    value = c(
      "water", "bay"
    )
  ) %>% 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() %$% 
  osm_polygons %>%
  dplyr::select(geometry) %>%
  sf::st_transform() %>% 
  sf::st_intersection(kiel)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = kiel,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "grey",
          colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = water,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "steelblue",
          colour = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = cycle,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          colour = "black")
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

OSM is a big source of data, isn't it? :)
There are couple of ways, how bicycle infrastructure is tagged in OSM. `highway=cycleway` that's one thing, however you can have `bicycle` tag added to any highway, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bicycle. So, usually you have to merge such things. Example below.

```r
bb <- osmdata::getbb("Kiel")

kiel <-osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*100) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "admin_level", 
    value = "6"
  ) |> 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

kiel <- kiel$osm_multipolygons |>
  subset(osm_id == "27021") |>
  sf::st_geometry()

cycle <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*100) |>
  # is there any better way to choose cycleways?
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(
    key = "highway", value = "cycleway"
    ) |> 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

cycle$osm_lines |>
  sf::st_intersection(kiel) |>
  subset(sf::st_is(geometry, "LINESTRING")) |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  sf::st_union() |>
  sf::st_length()

#> 15557.92 [m]
```

So, length of `highway=cycleway` is about 15 km. Let's see what we can get with `bicycle` tag:

```r
bicycle <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*100) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_features(c(
    "\"highway\" = \"cycleway\"",
    "\"bicycle\"")) |> 
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()
```

Now, we can check what values are in `bicycle`:

```r
unique(bicycle$osm_lines$bicycle)
#>  [1] "designated"        "yes"               "no"               
#>  [4] "use_sidepath"      "permissive"        "optional_sidepath"
#>  [7] "dismount"          NA                  "private"          
#> [10] "shared"
```

Let's use them:

```r
bicycle$osm_lines |>
  sf::st_intersection(kiel) |>
  subset(sf::st_is(geometry, "LINESTRING")) |>
  subset(highway == "cycleway" || 
           bicycle %in% c("designated", "yes", "use_sidepath",
                          "permissive", "optional_sidepath", "shared")) |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  sf::st_union() |>
  sf::st_length()

#> 468567.8 [m]
```

Not bad, 468 km, 30 times more.

And plots:

```r
cycle$osm_lines |>
  sf::st_intersection(kiel) |>
  subset(sf::st_is(geometry, "LINESTRING")) |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(col = "blue")
```

[image]

```r
bicycle$osm_lines |>
  sf::st_intersection(kiel) |>
  subset(sf::st_is(geometry, "LINESTRING")) |>
  subset(highway == "cycleway" || 
           bicycle %in% c("designated", "yes", "use_sidepath",
                          "permissive", "optional_sidepath", "shared")) |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(col = "green")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

BTW, cyclosm shows cycle routes as well, which are not considered yet. But in fact it depends, what's the aim of the study - only infrastructure, or touristic map.

Regards,
Grzegorz

PS. The details how the different tags are used to prepare data for cyclosm are in the [views.sql](https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/blob/master/views.sql) file.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this fantastic and super insightful answer. This really helped me grasp the osm structure beyond the specific issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Any time :). BTW, if you are interested in bicycle routes, you can check my sql way https://github.com/gsapijaszko/bike_map: `routes` and `routes_surface` in https://github.com/gsapijaszko/bike_map/blob/main/sql/views.sql. Shall be easy to port it to R as well

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out!